# Trouble setting color with setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(),int,int,int)

Tags: android

everyone. I am trying to set the color of a few words in a string using spannablestring.But for some reason I cant get the color of the string to change.

I have attached the relevant code

```
  String color = "some string"
  SpannableString span_color=  new SpannableString(color);
  span_color.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN),0,11,0);


  String print = "This is the whole string"+span_color;
  TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
  textview.setText(reminder);
```

In the Text View, I want the "This is the whole string" to be in the default color and the "some string" to be in green. but this is not happening.I am getting the entire string in the default color.I seem to be missing something important , but I cant figure out what .

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using "+" operator you get just string, not SpannableString. You should do something like this:

```
String color = "This is the whole string, color string";
SpannableString spanColor = new SpannableString(color);
spanColor.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN), color.indexOf("color string"), color.length(), 0);
TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
textview.setText(spanColor);
```

Comment: in the code you have provide , the entire string "this is the whole string, color string" will be in green right ? I just want a few words in it to be colored , not the whole string.

Comment: "color string" will be green.

Comment: not working ... I am still getting the whole string in black.

Comment: got it working in the end for me as well . You where right , thanks man:)